# No proper protective gear; what steps can I take to amend that?

Tags: united-states, health, safety

I work at a known chain of pet stores and I frequently come into contact with sick animals (who may bite). Our store hasn't had proper PPE (personal protective equipment) in weeks: no gloves (bite gloves or disposable), no masks to not inhale debris especially from the birds, frequently no paper towels, so on and so forth. Management is known to cut corners.

But given how frequently we workers have to take care of sick and unhealthy animals with easily spreadable zoonotic diseases (salmonella, ringworm, etc), pick up after people's dogs (if the owners decide not to do it), etc., I feel like the store not offering proper PPE is a violation somehow. especially in this type of environment.

It's too easy to get sick or bit here and it seems as if management only cares about the bottom line and not the workers. Groomers for example have to deal with crazy dogs without any real protection because they may face consequences if they refuse. Dogs need vaccinations to get groomed and do training, but any dog can walk in the store without such vaccinations if the owner isn't there for grooming or training. There's no simple first aid kits either, and if you get bit by a small animal, nobody writes up an incident report unless it's bad.

I don't want to call HR because they have a way of finding out who you are and you can face consequences or get written up... for valid complaints. It's a tough situation. Are there any suggestions on what I can do? (Besides quitting).

Comment: A few pertinent quesitons: Is this simply out of concern for potential illness, or have there been a notable number of illnesses/injuries passed this way?  Do you know if there are regulations (OSHA or the like) that pertain but are not being followed?  Are other pet stores in the area likewise lax, or is your company particularly bad with respect to this?

Comment: "Are there any suggestions on what I can do? (Besides quit lol).. thanks."  Seek a lawyer who specializes in job site conditions and health violations

Comment: Location would help - if you're in the US, OSHA would be someone to contact.

Comment: Everything you need is here: https://www.osha.gov/workers/index.html

Comment: It all comes down to country. I'm sure in USA and parts of Europe you have a lot of laws surrounding this. Other countries might not.

Comment: So, yeah, adding a country tag would help.

Comment: @dwizum Only if OP is working in the US.

Comment: I am in the us, and I've been reading that ppe is mandatory for a company to supply

Comment: Your local health department would be another contact point. OSHA is a great one, and they may take a long time to respond. A local health department will be faster, but it won't have the same teeth.

Comment: One question to address with management:  Are they no longer attempting to purchase PPE, or are orders of PPE not being filled?  Supply chain problems are getting worse almost weekly, and PPE that can be used for human care is getting priority, now.

Answer (score 16):

OSHA dictates PPE must be provided where risks occur and that the employer must pay for it.  The employer is responsible for assessing the PPE requirements for performing work in the workplace and following through on providing it.  Failure to comply has major financial and reputational consequences.  Should your employer not take worker safety seriously an anonymous tip line exists to report and whistleblower supports exist should retaliation occur.  Links provided below to support these points.

As advice, your employer has opted to take profits over worker safety.  I wouldn't bother complaining to them directly as you paint a target on yourself.  I would make an anonymous complaint to OSHA and let the process run its course.  Once audited it is typically more expensive to be out of compliance rather than pay for proper worker protections.

https://www.osha.gov/pls/oshaweb/owadisp.show_document?p_id=9777&p_table=STANDARDS

https://www.osha.gov/dte/outreach/intro_osha/7_employee_ppe.pdf

https://www.osha.gov/penalties/

https://www.oshaeducationcenter.com/articles/reporting-labor-violations/

https://www.osha.gov/whistleblower/WBComplaint.html

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any suggestions on what I can do?

Buying your own PPE as suggested in the other answer is a way, if you can and are willing to cover it with your money.

For the "communal" PPE (First Aid, bandages, etc.) you can *coordinate with the rest of your coworkers and buy that equipment together*. As it is also of their interest, they will surely be willing to do it.

An alternative I can think of is to **raise your concern to management or HR *as a group***. You say that the situation is tough, and I also perceive that your coworkers and you may be a bit afraid to ask/complain... but if you organize all or the majority of your coworkers, and ask/raise your concerns it will be more difficult for management to cut corners or dismiss your request (not to mention to attempt to write all of you up).

If there is some trade Union for your profession, that would also be a solid resource to contact.

As mentioned in comment, it is not clear what your location is. If you are in the USA, [OSHA](https://www.osha.gov/workers/index.html) would be the most adequate contact you could reach out. If you are in Europe, most likely there exists an equivalent to OSHA you can contact

Now, if you are in other countries that don't have these facilities (like it is my case) things are indeed more difficult and delicate. Case in which you will have to tread lightly if raising this (and case where you should consider buying your PPE on your own in the meantime, as your safety is paramount here).

Comment: In the UK there's the Health and Safety Executive (https://www.hse.gov.uk/) There's an option under 'contact us' to report work places in violation.

Comment: @Smock thanks for the useful link :) good thing OP clarified their location

Comment: well now they've done that I've +1'd your answer. Shall I leave my comment in case someone see's this question from the UK?

Comment: Yes that would be useful

Answer (score -1):

Buy your own ppe.  This will keep you safe and might spark discussion among others who feel the same to raise it with management.

Comment: The PPE OP needs could be expensive and/or require many components. Asking OP to cover it with their own money is indeed a way, but they will have to cover it with their own money, something that could not be feasible or escalate (some equipment could need replacement every x time)

Comment: In Australia if you buy your own PPE it is tax deductible. And as mentioned can spark discussion among others.

Comment: @solarflare we currently ignore if OP is in Australia. A location tag will *greatly* help here. Hopefully in OPs location PPE is also tax deductible.

Comment: At this point I have bought my own ppe, I do not want to risk sickness or injury. I'm also allergic to one of the animals here

Comment: Also, sorry about the location thing, i'm in the us. I'm new to this forum and pn mobile. I'll look to see if I can add it.